# How to adjust the direction of arrow in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg, d3.js

I copy the code from Mike Bostock's slides (using the newest version of d3.js)

The graph can be viewed at:
http://cistrome.org/~hanfei/d3/bad_arrow/c.html

However, I found some strange behavior of the markers(arrows), which is ok in `Safari` but becomes wrong in `Firefox`. (See the screenshot below)

In Safari:
[image: In Safari]

In Firefox(14.0.1 newest):
[image: In Firefox]

Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: Might help to mention this ONLY happens on Firefox 14+, I just tested it on 12 and it worked on 12.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug appeared in Firefox 13. It is fixed in Firefox 15 by [bug 769115](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=769115) You could either download a beta of Firefox 15 or wait till the release.